# Android Webview Loading resources from expired Cache

Tags: javascript, android, caching, webview

I am creating a hybrid app where UI is on server and I use webview in my application and use native features only where necessary(where hardware access is needed).

My problem is sometimes Webview loads resources from cache even when newer resources (like javascript etc) are uploaded on server.  I don't face this problem when I open the same URL from a Browser on computer at the same time.  How can I make sure that webview updates its content from server.  This behavior is also not predictable since webview updates its cache eventually but after many page loads.

Clearing cache on every run or LOAD_NO_CACHE mode are not an option since I want the cache functionality(but not at the risk of old resources being loaded from cache when newer are available on server).

Here is the code snippet.  browser.loadURL(); is being called elsewhere in application

```
    browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser);
    progress_bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);


    browser.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    browser.setWebChromeClient( .... )
    browser.setWebViewClient( .... )  // omitted complete functions to save space
```

Answer (score 2):

Something I did on a web application was to add a phoney version flag to my JavaScript and CSS files in the script and link tags. So, it looked something like this on the web side. This makes the browser think the resources is different and causes it to reload it.

```
<link href="./css/my_style.css?version=1.0" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="./js/my_script.js?version=1.3" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you want to control this on the app side of things. You can add a kind of "expires date" in your SharedPreferences file. I do this for an image cache I have in some applications. Basically, you clear the cache when that date passes. It would look something like this.

```
String expireDateString = getSharedPreferences("WebviewExpireCache", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Date today = new Date();
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
if(today.after(format.parse(expireDateString ))){
    browser.clearCache(true);
}
```